# SpriteKit: Add SKSpriteNodes To The View

Tags: swift, view, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

I basically want to add a SKSpriteNode to the screen and I have no idea where the mistake it. So I include pictures of my three classes participating in this problem. I created a class for all the background stuff. There I use the function `addChild()` to add my 56 Nodes to the View but they do not appear on the screen. Theoretically (for me) everything should work.

[image: GameViewController]

[image: GameScene]

[image: Background]

Hopefully you can help me adding the Nodes to the screen!

Edit: Updated the pictures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call this:

```
GameScene().addChild(image)
```

you every time inside `for` create the local `GameScene` object, add `image` to this object and when you move to the next iteration of the loop, this object is destroyed. In fact, after your loop thire is no one `GameScene` object.

Second, you don't need to use `var image = SKSpriteNode()` in your `hintergrund` object. You every time set this reference to new object.

You have the cross references in code, try to make somthing like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    ...
    override func didMoveToView(view: UIView) {
        hintergrund.setBackgroundForScene(self, width: screenWidht)
    }
}

class hintergrund {
    ...
    class func setBackgroundForScene(gameScene: GameScene, width: CGFloat) {
        ...
        for (...) {
            ...
            gameScene.addChild(image)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your explanation makes sense and I applied the changes on my code. Sadly it still doesn't work.

Comment: @LukasKöhl you're doing a similar mistake and to the creation of `hintergrund` object in this line `hintergrund.setupBackground(screenWidth)`. Object that created in this line of code will be deleted after ending `didMoveToView` method

Comment: When I am doing the same thing with `let background = hintergrund()` and `background.setupBackground(screenWidth)`  does not work for me. I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. In the first part of code I wrote.

Comment: @LukasKöhl you are all very bad to the interaction of objects with each other, I've edited the answer, look it

Comment: @LukasKöhl And not add screenshots of the next time, add with a printed code

Comment: Sorry for adding screenshots. All in all I know some basics but the connection between classes is somehow very difficult to understand. Thanks for updating the answer. It works perfectly. I still don't know how the cross reverence works. I am going to look it up though.

Comment: @LukasKöhl And if you will use static method in your `hintergrund` class you can not use your instance members like `xPose`, you need to encapsulate them inside the static method or don't use static method and create `hintergrund` object with calling `func setBackgroundForScene(gameScene: GameScene, width: CGFloat)` that will be defined without `class` keyword befor `func ...`

Comment: For an easy solution I moved all members like `xPos` inside the `class func setBackgroundForScene(gameScene: GameScene, width: CGFloat)`